# Creation of jar failing in Intelij: The Java JAR file “ObjectFinder.jar” could not be launched

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, manifest, artifact

I'm trying to create a jar file and currently receive the "The Java JAR file “ObjectFinder.jar” could not be launched." error when clicking. I have followed the procedures that are provided on the web and on stackoverflow but to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what I am missing:

File -> project -> artifacts -> + -> jar -> from modules with dependencies -> main class -> main (selected from the Main Class drop down) -> apply

Build -> build artifacts

The structure of my project and the content of the manifest is:

[image]

and the content of the main file is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceWindow interfaceWindow = new InterfaceWindow();
        interfaceWindow.setInterfaceWindow();
    }
}
```

I've double clicked the jar file and used java -jar ObjectFinder.jar  to attempt to run it.

Comment: Make sure the Jar file is [packaged correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)#Executable_JAR_files): that it has `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file with Main class specified. Note that Maven does not copy resource files from **source** directories. So it is better to create `META-INF` directory with the manifest file in **resources** folder.

Comment: There is also a dedicated **Jar** Application run configuration type in IDE you can use to run the runnable jars: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#run_jar_artifact